# Looking to scrape data from google search results. Unable to driver.get the links without error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am looking to scrape data from google search and import the data into a pandas data frame. Unfortunately, every time I run the code below it returns with InvalidArgumentException.

```
Jobdata = []
Lnks = []
for x in range(0,20,10):
    driver.get(f'https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Alinkedin.com%2F+AND+%22managing+director+%40+Morgan+Stanley%22+AND+%22New+York+City+Metropolitan+Area%22&rlz=1C1ONGR_enUS1012US1012&ei=7totZJioCr6dptQPi4qR4Ag&ved=0ahUKEwiY1_KOy5P-AhW-jokEHQtFBIwQ4dUDCBA&oq=site%3Alinkedin.com%2F+AND+%22managing+director+%40+Morgan+Stanley%22+AND+%22New+York+City+Metropolitan+Area%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQDEoECEEYAFAAWABgAGgAcAB4AIABAIgBAJIBAJgBAA&sclient=gws-wiz-serp')
    sleep(randint(3,5))
    linkedin_urls = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='yuRUbf']")))]
    Lnks.append(linkedin_urls)

for x in Lnks:
    for i in x:

            driver.get(i)
            sleep(randint(3,5))
```

Error occurs on driver.get(i)

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of the URLs in the Lnks list is wrong
So for debugging I would suggest to add this line before running driver.get(i)

```
for x in Lnks:
    for i in x:
        print(i)
        driver.get(i)
        sleep(randint(3,5))
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for getting back to me unfortunately no difference.

Comment: My solution is not supposed to solve the problem it's just for debugging, the problem is probably in one of the URLs, can you please share the list of the URLs (Which are printed in the print line)?